# Passing parameters into a model/table function

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to pass a value called schoolYear which right now is 2019 lets say or whatever the user chooses really. Below is executed once the user selected submit and it executed a if post request then proceeds onto the edit controller via screen 2. on screen 2 I have a edit function with schoolYear being passed into it and a echo returning 2019 the correct value i choose. Great! Now i am struggling with passing that particular parameter into the table function so it can be used as shown. Can someone point me in the right direction, Thanks

Right now i get no error messages but if i take a look at the sql being passed, it is showing FiscalYear = 0 in the sql being executed which means $schoolyear is not being set from my controller hmmmmmm

```
        return $this->redirect([
                'controller' => 'MassUpdateCalender',
                'action' => 'edit',
                $schoolYear,
                $allElementary,
            ]);

public function edit($schoolYear)
{
    $InformationCalenderTable = $this->loadModel('MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar');

        echo $schoolYear;   
    $elementarySchools = $InformationCalenderTable->getSchoolsByLevel('0%', $schoolYear);

public function getSchoolsByLevel($schoolYear, string $code = '0', string $isSummerSchool = '0')
{
    $query = $this->find()
    ->where([
        'FiscalYear' => $schoolYear,
        'DistrictCode' => 'MA',
        'summerSchool' => $isSummerSchool,
        'SchoolCode like' => $code,
    ]); 
    return $query->toArray();        
}
```

The outcome will return a list of all the schools with that where criteria.

Comment: You are passing a hardcoded `0%` as the `$schoolYear` argument!?

Comment: Remove the 1st parameter that is '0%' in this line, $InformationCalenderTable->getSchoolsByLevel('0%', $schoolYear);, so new line will be **$InformationCalenderTable->getSchoolsByLevel($schoolYear);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to get schools based on what year they are in. For that, do this:

```
function edit($schoolYear) {
    $this->loadModel('MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar');
    $elementarySchools = $this->MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar->find('all', array('conditions' => array('MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar.FiscalYear' => $schoolYear)));
}
```

However, if you are trying to execute the query in your getSchoolsByLevel function, do this:

```
function edit($schoolYear) {
    $this->loadModel('MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar');
    $code = $isSummerSchool = 0;
    $elementarySchools = $this->MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar->find('all', array('conditions' => array('FiscalYear' => $schoolYear, 'DistrictCode' => 'MA', 'summerSchool' => $isSummerSchool, 'SchoolCode LIKE' => $code)));
}
```

If you want to break out your function, like in your example, do this:

```
function edit($schoolYear) {
    $this->loadModel('MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar');
    $elementarySchools = $this->_getSchoolsByLevel($schoolYear);
}

function _getSchoolsByLevel($schoolYear, string $code = '0', string $isSummerSchool = '0') {
    return $this->MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar->find('all', array('conditions' => array('FiscalYear' => $schoolYear, 'DistrictCode' => 'MA', 'summerSchool' => $isSummerSchool, 'SchoolCode LIKE' => $code)));
}
```

Notes:

1. Put var $uses = array('MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar'); at the top of your controller class, so you don't have to keep loading the model.
2. The underscore before the function denotes a private function. Use this so that users can't go to the MMSDvSchoolFromCalendar/getSchoolsByLevel page.